# how to relate this data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my app, a `subject` has_many `goals` and each `goal` belongs to a `subject`.

This relationship makes the most sense, but I'm wondering how to use it in practice.  For example - after a given time frame, each subject's goals should be evaluated, but they'll be evaluated on a student-by-student basis.

so let's say

- goal.1 = "drink an entire gallon of milk without vomiting"
- student.1 = "Lisa"

And let's also say Lisa is really quite good at holding her bile - so **for goal.1, Student.1 = 5**.  Goals are tied to subjects, so I know that goal.1 belongs to English, Math, etc, but what's the best way to model the relationship that `goals` have to `students` when the students are being evaluated?  They should also be able to be evaluated several times in a given period.

Comment: Anything you have tried yet building in the application?

Comment: I had a column in the `student` table called `score` but had problems relating it to more than one goal and actually just gave up on that because it seemed like the logic was too convoluted.  I was considering a join table between `students` and `goals` with a has_many:through relationship, but wasn't sure exactly how that would work so I thought I'd ask here first to see if there was a simple solution I was overlooking.  Fair question though, I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following covers your description:

```
Subject
  has_many :goals
end

Goal
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :evaluations
end

Student 
  has_many :evaluations
end

Evaluation 
  belongs_to :goal 
  belongs_to :student

  # columns: score, date
end
```

The evaluation object allows a student to have many evaluations for many goals over a period of time.